# How can I reload screen after fetch data from server nodejs to expo app and in the shared compenent that use that data

Tags: react-native, expo, use-effect

I am just try to learn mobile app and can't reload screen after fetch data

```
export default function Store({ route, navigation }) {

const [products, setProducts] = useState([])

<ShowProduct  products={products}/>

}
```

this is just I did till now when I add product or delete not effect and I try to use  useEffect still the same

Comment: Why don't you perform `fetch` inside `ShowProduct` screen and then use it?

Comment: I have function on the Store screen addProduct and on ShowProduct screen I can't use useeffect to reload this data everytime

Comment: show the full code then maybe I can help you with a solution